# Usar @ para ignorar ou if/else?

Tags: php

Em `PHP`, usamos métodos `POST` e `GET` (além do `REQUEST`) para adquirir as variáveis passadas pelo `HTML`, porém podemos passar por situações inconvenientes ao resgatar essas chaves, como por exemplo, ter a exibição de notícias e alertas informando que as variáveis não puderam receber um valor, como podemos ver no exemplo:

```
<?php
    $variavel = $_REQUEST['valor'];
    //na primeira execução da página não teremos a chave 'valor'
?>

<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="valor"/>
    <input type="submit" value="..."/>
</form>
```

E veremos o seguinte alerta:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: valor in ..\page.php on
>   line 2 Call Stack
>
> *#Time   Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0011  131632  {main}( )   ..\page.php:0*

### Para solucionar isso temos duas opções:

**--** Usar `@` antes da declaração, que significa ignorar as notícias e
   avisos;

```
<?php
@$variavel = $_REQUEST['valor'];
?>
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="valor"/>
    <input type="submit" value="..."/>
</form>
```

**--** Fazer condições para tratar do valor da variável;

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['valor']))
    $variavel = $_REQUEST['valor'];
else
    $variavel = NULL;
?>
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="valor"/>
    <input type="submit" value="..."/>
</form>
```

Quero saber qual a melhor forma de se tratar isso, eu pessoalmente prefiro a segunda, pois para mim a primeira forma parece mais uma 'gambiarra', mas quero ver a opinião de vocês e ver qual método é mais usado.